# viewport only shows a small area of my scene

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, object-mode, select

I have some issues with my viewport. It only shows a small area of my scene with solid shading. Also only vertices within this area can be selected. In object mode a pyramid shows up. It limits the viewable area. I added two screenshots, one with viewport shading, to show you, that only a view vertices are selectable, and one with solid shading in object mode to show you the pyramid.

Has anyone an idea how this could be fixes?

Thank you! Janek

[image] [image]

Comment: you've must have made a View Regions (alt B), try alt B again

Comment: Thank you, this worked :)